# Incorrect type conversion with cx_Oracle and sqlalchemy queries

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, type-conversion, cx-oracle

I have a `cx_Oracle` engine defined as follows:

```
e = create_engine('oracle://username:password@(DESCRIPTION='
                  '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))'
                  '(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLPDB1.localdomain)))')
```

If I make two queries of different data types (first `int`, then `str`) using RAW SQL like this:

```
print(e.execute('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL').scalar())
print(e.execute("SELECT 'qwerty' FROM DUAL").scalar())
```

it works fine. And, as expected, I get

```
1
'qwerty'
```

However when I use SQLAlchemy to build the queries like this:

```
print(e.execute(sa.select([sa.literal(1)])).scalar())
print(e.execute(sa.select([sa.literal('qwerty')])).scalar())
```

the first query runs successfully printing `1`, but the second one fails with:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01722: invalid number [SQL: 'SELECT :param_1 AS anon_1 FROM DUAL'] [parameters: {'param_1': 'qwerty'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

It looks like after the first query is done, something inside the engine/dialect machinery somehow assumes that all subsequent queries will also require an integer result value (If I skip the integer query, then there are no errors). Don't know if it's a driver or SA issue.

Creating a new engine instance for every query kind of fixes the problem, but really isn't the solution I'm hoping for.

versions:

```
DB: Oracle Database Server 12.2.0.1
Oracle tools: 18.3.0.0.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.17
cx-Oracle==7.1.0
```